# Does ${S_n\over \Bbb E (S_n)}$ converges in probability?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, expected-value, convergence

> $X_n\sim Poi(\lambda_n)$ ,$X_i$'s are independent and $\sum\limits_1^\infty\lambda_n=\infty.$ Define $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ . Is it true that $${S_n\over \Bbb E (S_n)}$$ converges *in probability*?

I don't know what it converges to, but I guess it should be $1$.

Comment: It seems to be a handbook exercise or homework, so please refer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and use `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, if the question looks like a homework question, but it was what a group of mine came across while doing something bigger, . so it isn't "homework" (in the true sense). However, if just adding a `[self-study]` tag will prevent it from being closed, I am willing to add it. Should I?

Comment: given your comment, you probably do not have to. I'd recommend leaving your comment at place so someone else wouldn't consider it as a homework and make similar suggestions.

Comment: @Tim Should I add my comment as an edit to the question itself?

Comment: I do not think there is such need :) Anyway, in the future if in doubt you can always start your question like "This may sound like a homework but..." since homework questions have a special treatment in here.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the tip.. :-) . BTW, can you help me with the question?

Comment: Because [sums of Poissons are Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Sums_of_Poisson-distributed_random_variables), your question asks about the limiting value of Poisson$(\mu_n)/\mu_n$ as $\mu_n\to\infty$. That's easy to work out because these distributions have mean $1$, variance $1/\mu_n$, (and even approach Normality when suitably standardized).