# How ${S_n\over E(S_n)}\xrightarrow{a.s.}1$?

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, convergence

Let $X_n$ be independent **Poission** random variables with mean $\lambda_n$ and $\sum_n\lambda_n=\infty$. Let $S_n=\sum_1^n X_i$ . How to show that ${S_n\over E(S_n)}\xrightarrow{a.s.}1$ ?

I am not getting how to start. Please  help.

Comment: Actually, you did ask this very similar question a week ago: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/242681/7224

Comment: @Xi'an similar, not same. I want an answer to this.

Comment: One assumes this is either homework or self-study; if so, please use the appropriate tag.  We prefer to give guidance on self-study questions rather than just an answer.

Comment: Crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000313/

Comment: Start from the definition of almost sure convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard result on the sum of $n$ independent Poisson variables, $X_1,..,X_n$, is, that:

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \sim Poisson\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} X_i \right) $$

In your case that amouns to $S_n \sim Poisson(n\lambda)$. Then

$$ Y_n = \frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E} S_n} $$

must follow some distribution (*not* Poisson however) that has moments:

$$ \mathbb{E} Y_n = 1, \qquad \mathbb{V} Y_n = \frac{1}{n^2} $$

As $n$ tends to infinity the variance converges to $0$ and thus $Y_n \overset{P}{\to} 1$

EDIT: The sequence does indeed converge almost surely as well. You want to show that

$$ P\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Y_n = 1\right) = 1 $$

Rewrite the above probability (hint: part of $Y_n$ is entirely deterministic) and consider the strong law of large numbers, and you will have shown almost sure convergence.

Comment: Good work! But I asked for **almost sure** convergence

Comment: Welcome to the site, @NethanelAristotole. Please be cautious when answering `[self-study]` questions. We only give hints, & not full answers. You can read our policy [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung Thanks for the heads up, I didn't know that - I will remember that.

Comment: @Qwerty I see, didn't notice. I'll edit my answer, and respond as a hint instead